# How do you check if string ends with another string in Ada?

Tags: string, ada

There are canonical answers to this question for every popular language, even though that answer usually boils down to: "Use string.endsWith() from the standard library". For Ada, as far as I can find in [the docs for the Fixed String package](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-4-3.html), there is no string.endswith function.

So, given two fixed strings A and B, how do you check if A ends with B?

```
declare
   A : constant String := "John Johnson";
   B : constant String := "son";
begin
   if A.Ends_With(B) then -- this doesn't compile
      Put_Line ("Yay!");
   end if;
end
```

My intent is to establish a standard answer for Ada.

Comment: I don't think we can answer this properly without a better specification of `Ends_With`. While `Ada.Strings.Fixed.Tail` works in the expected cases, we need to also know what `Ends_With` should do in the less common cases (`A'Length < B'Length or B = ""`).

Comment: It should answer as if you had asked a person. Does "hi" end in "longer than hi" ? No. If A is shorter than B, A cannot possibly end in B. And if B is empty, the answer should always be Yes.

Comment: wow ada, a blast from the past

Comment: Yeah, incredible. As old as the "++" of C++!

Comment: To my mind, asking if a string ends with the null string is meaningless, but given this specification, I'd have given Zerte's answer (modified into an expression function by Simon Wright).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A slight simplification of Simon's answer:

```
function Ends_With (Source, Pattern : String) return Boolean is
begin
   return Pattern'Length <= Source'Length 
     and then Source (Source'Last - Pattern'Length + 1 .. Source'Last) = Pattern;
end Ends_With;
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, here's a possible solution:

**main.adb**

```
with Ada.Text_IO;       use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Strings.Fixed; use Ada.Strings.Fixed;

procedure Main is

   A : constant String := "John Johnson";
   B : constant String := "son";

begin

   if Tail (A, B'Length) = B then
      Put_Line ("Yay!");
   end if;

end Main;
```

**output**

```
$ ./main
Yay!
```

---

**UPDATE (2)**

Another update (thanks @Brian Drummond for the comment; comment disappeared though), again using `Tail`. This is now almost identical to @Zerte's answer, except for the dependency on `Ada.Strings.Fixed`:

**main.adb**

```
with Ada.Text_IO;       use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Strings.Fixed; use Ada.Strings.Fixed;
with Ada.Assertions;    use Ada.Assertions;

procedure Main is

   function Ends_With (Source, Pattern : String) return Boolean is
   begin
      return Source'Length >= Pattern'Length and then
        Tail (Source, Pattern'Length) = Pattern;
   end Ends_With;   

begin

   Assert (Ends_With ("John Johnson", "son")  = True);
   Assert (Ends_With ("hi", "longer than hi") = False);

   Assert (Ends_With (""  , ""  ) = True);
   Assert (Ends_With (" " , ""  ) = True);
   Assert (Ends_With (""  , " " ) = False);
   Assert (Ends_With (" " , " " ) = True);

   Assert (Ends_With ("n ", "n ") = True);
   Assert (Ends_With (" n", "n" ) = True);
   Assert (Ends_With ("n" , " n") = False);
   Assert (Ends_With (" n", " n") = True);

   Put_Line ("All OK.");

end Main;
```

**output**

```
$ ./main
All OK.
```

Comment: and a third, using the `Index` function

Comment: note this correctly handles the case where A is shorter than B; because Tail prepends spaces rather than raising an error, and those spaces make the equality comparison return False.

Comment: ...unless you have a case like `A = "n"` and `B = "  n"`.

Comment: Comment disappeared because I read further and found it duplicated Zerte's answer (upvoted)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example without any explicit loops.

```
with Ada.Assertions; use Ada.Assertions;
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   function Ends_With(Source : String; Pattern : String) return Boolean is
      result : Boolean := False;
   begin
      if Pattern'Length <= Source'Length then
         if Pattern'Length > 0 then
            result := Source((Source'Last - Pattern'Length + 1)..Source'Last) = Pattern;
         else 
            result := True;
         end if;
      end if;
      return result;
   end Ends_With;

begin

   Assert (Ends_With ("John Johnson", "son") = True);


   Assert (Ends_With (""  , ""  ) = True);
   Assert (Ends_With (" " , ""  ) = True);
   Assert (Ends_With (""  , " " ) = False);
   Assert (Ends_With (" " , " " ) = True);   

   Assert (Ends_With (""  , "n" ) = False);
   Assert (Ends_With ("n"  , "" ) = True);

   Assert (Ends_With ("n ", "n ") = True);
   Assert (Ends_With (" n", "n" ) = True);
   Assert (Ends_With ("n" , " n") = False);
   Assert (Ends_With (" n", " n") = True);

   Put_Line("All OK");
end Main;
```

Answer (score 2):

As a slight simplification of [Jim’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62090863/40851), this works too:

```
   function Ends_With (Source, Pattern : String) return Boolean is
   begin
      if Pattern'Length > Source'Length then
         return False;
      else
         return Source (Source'Last - Pattern'Length + 1 .. Source'Last)
           = Pattern;
      end if;
   end Ends_With;
```

but, even better (thanks, Zerte),

```
function Ends_With (Source, Pattern : String) return Boolean is
  (Pattern'Length <= Source'Length and then
     Source (Source'Last - Pattern'Length + 1 .. Source'Last) = Pattern);
```